# How to fill all of these fields in QoS?

Tags: router, internet, speed, mac-address, qos

I want to make the internet speed of a specific user on my router slow, but i have no background about these things.

Can you tell me what should i put on each field?

[image: this is what i'm talking about]

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I can’t believe that you don’t know about [this](https://meta.superuser.com/q/13627/150988#13632 "(notes on editing image markdown)").

Comment: Eh. It's a new question and it was a quick fix I did off my phone cause it turned up on a smoke detector feed

Comment: Maybe I’m wrong, but it looks like you can only configure how packages are queued. You cannot configure the queue itself, which is what would be required to limit bandwidth.